# Test Selective activity using robotium

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I am trying to automate test cases using robotium. The problem that I am facing is that my app has, like all apps, lots of activities. So I dont want to test the whole application again and again, but only specific activity. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

I cheat - I add a simple activity with buttons that can launch any other activity, with sample parameters, where needed. I then use Robotium to launch a specific activity and test it, rather than the full application. Once this is done though, I pretty much follow http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html to make sure I do proper, full-cover testing for my application.

The last step is to remove this dummy "menu" activity from the application.

Answer (score 0):

in **constructor** of robotium test we write `super("com.example.helloworld1",MainActivity.class);` where instead of **MainActiviry.class** we can write **OwnActivity.class**. Here **OwnActivity** is the activity from where we want to start testing our application.